# Sharepoint Workflows and Managed Term Sets

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, document-library, content-type, workflow-variable

Platform: Sharepoint 2010 with Sharepoint Designer 2010

Are there any explanations out there on how to create a workflow with an email template that is sent to certain people based on a taxonomy term set choice?

For example: I start with a 'Shared Documents' library that will house internal procedures and processes etc. As we upload files we are using term sets to 'filter' and identify which area of the business this procedure relates to yet keeping it all in one place.

My dilemma: I have two areas of the business that sit in two different geographical locations. What i want is to have a central shared document upload area for Team 1 and Team 2.  When a document is uploaded you have to choose a Term Set of Team 1/2 to associate with the document. Based on a term set selected I want to send an email to the team leaders and start an approval workflow.

Scenario 1: Upload document to shared area, select term set Team 1 and click upload. Documents then require review for typos/grammar etc so workflow starts the approval process and sends all emails to Team 1.

Scenario 2: Same as above but this time uploading documents for Team 2

Any help would be gratefully appreciated, I have spent several hours looking for an answer and I'm either missing something completely or really not finding the information.

Comment: Are you using SharePoint designer to create the workflow? Also what version of SharePoint are you using as it changed quite a bit in 2013

Comment: Hi Ryan,

Yes I'm using SPD2010, also the site is 2010.  Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented a very similar solution for our news section. What I ended up doing was:

I used the built in Target Audience field SharePoint offers (you might need to enable this feature). In audience targeting you can create SharePoint groups, Global Audiences or Distribution/Security Groups (groups for Team1 and Team2 for example). In the workflow you can check which audience/s is/are selected and send emails to the right team leader.

Another huge advantage of this approach is that only the users from the selected group will be able to see the files/items.